# Is exactextract taking shortcuts and sacrificing accuracy when calculating zonal statistics in R?

Tags: r, gis

I've been calculating zonal statistics in R, first using the `raster::extract` function and then using the `exactextractr::exactextract` function. I compared the results of both to the results of zonal statistics I calculated by hand in QGIS. The results from the raster extract function match the QGIS results to several decimal places, whereas the exact extract function provides results that are close but a bit off:

| QGIS Results | Raster Extract | Exact Extract |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 44.08599 | 44.08599 | 44.23548 |
| 56.82178 | 56.82178 | 56.90371 |
| 41.57019 | 41.57019 | 41.69187 |
| 55.97451 | 55.97451 | 56.02464 |

The pro to using exact extract is that it is MUCH MUCH faster than the raster extract function - but at what cost? Is the increased speed a result of "cutting corners" and less accurate results? And if so, exactly how much accuracy am I losing? I'm trying to determine if it's worth saving the time if I end up with worse results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`exactextractr` is faster *and* more precise because it *literally cuts corners* (it considers fractions of raster cells, not only entire cells). `terra::extract` is also reasonably fast.

Comment: Aha! Good to know. I can rest easy now, thanks!